# how to call Sass variable in a Vue file

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vue-component

There is a `variables.scss` file in a project which defines a variable and assigns it a color like this:
`$contrast: #edebe4`
The current use of the `$contrast` variable is to set other variables within the `variables.scss` file.

Now there is a specific `.vue` file that's used to render data to the browser and it contains this line of code in its template:
`<div style="background-color: #edebe4">`

When I change that line to
`<div style="background-color: $contrast">`
the desired background color disappears from that element.

Is there a way to get that element to recognize the `$contrast` variable so that whenever the value of `$contrast` is changed that change flows through automatically to this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import `variables.scss` into your `.vue`

```
...
<style lang="scss">
@import "variables.scss"
</style>
```

Comment: This is preferable to the way I had figured out how to do it because this avoids cluttering up `variables.scss` with classes.  It was necessary to add `@` infront of the `import` word to get this to work.   My solution post has been amended so the final solution is clear to others reading this thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can make scss variables available globally (in each component). Just add this to `vue.config.js`:

```
css: {
  loaderOptions: {
    scss: {
      additionalData: `@import "~@/variables.scss";`
    }
  }
}
```

More info [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders)

Answer (score 0):

This worked -

in `variables.scss` file added

```
.contrast-background {
    background-color: $contrast;
}
```

in `.vue` file changed element to this

```
<div class="contrast-background">
```

***Amendment -***

Here is the final solution that was implemented, which was made possible by @Finn's post -

Changes to `.vue` file:
added this

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "@/layout/design/variables.scss";

    .contrast-background {
    background-color: $contrast;
}
</style>
```

and changed element to this

```
<div class="contrast-background">
```

This approach avoids changes to the `variables.scss` file.